# Angular js Grid is not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Below is my code

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="myApp">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>        
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/master/ui-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/master/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('MyCtrl1', function ($scope) {
            $scope.today = new Date();
        });
        app.controller('MyCtrl2', function ($scope) {
            $scope.myData = [{ name: "Moroni", age: 50 },
                             { name: "Tiancum", age: 43 },
                             { name: "Jacob", age: 27 },
                             { name: "Nephi", age: 29 },
                             { name: "Enos", age: 34 }];
            $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' };
        });
    </script>
</head> 
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div ng-controller="MyCtrl1">
            <div class="jumbotron">
            </div>
            <div class="container container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="table table-hover" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p class="text-right">{{ today | date }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-controller="MyCtrl2">
            <div class="table table-hover" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new in angular js , referring Examples from http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-grid/

This code should display a grid (using ng-grid) But its not

What's wrong in this example ??

Comment: Try `$scope.gridOptions = { data: $scope.myData};`

Comment: Tried But does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't actually setting your data with this line. You are setting the value of `$scope.gridOptions.data` to a string literal of 'myData'.

```
$scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' };
```

What you need to do is this (minimally):

```
$scope.gridOptions = { data: $scope.myData };
```

Since you don't need the data on scope directly, you could do this instead:

```
var myData = [{ name: "Moroni", age: 50 },
                 { name: "Tiancum", age: 43 },
                 { name: "Jacob", age: 27 },
                 { name: "Nephi", age: 29 },
                 { name: "Enos", age: 34 }];
$scope.gridOptions = { data: myData };
```

Or:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: [
           { name: "Moroni", age: 50 },
           { name: "Tiancum", age: 43 },
           { name: "Jacob", age: 27 },
           { name: "Nephi", age: 29 },
           { name: "Enos", age: 34 }
    ]
};
```

In your module declaration, you also need to change to this. That tells your module that it's going to use this library. Without it, you won't load the `ui-grid` directive that is used to create the grid.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.grid']);
```

Now, all that said, I am not sure about your use of bootstrap classes here. Generally, the grid has it's own CSS found [here](http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.min.css). If you grid displays poorly, or not at all (not sure what to expect), then you should use that stylesheet and set your HTML to this. Regardless, you need to change `ng-grid` to `ui-grid`. `ng-grid` is from much older versions.

```
<div class="grid" ui-grid="gridOptions"></div>
```

Comment: Changed 'myData ' to myData  and injected ['ui.grid'] too , but still no result

Comment: What do you see in the console?

Comment: It was ui-grid="gridOptions" , Thanks , Its showing now , One question - how can I inject multiple dependency in app

Comment: Nice, no problem! For multiple deps, just do `angular.module('myApp', ['ui.grid','another.dependency']);`

Comment: Also, for curiosity sake, does it display properly without setting the class to 'grid' and only using boostrap classes?

Comment: Yes , it display well without using class grid , with only using bootstrap class

Comment: Fantastic, I will have to try. Sad I never did :(. We all learned something today..

Comment: Please Up vote the Question too , if you think it was learning for both